# Batch video conversion - With subtitle burn-in

Tags: windows, batch, conversion, video-conversion

**I want to convert a folder of .mkv files for online use.**
By this, I mean burning in the subtitles and if possible, adding two different languages (so Youtube will let the users choose.)

**Handbrake did the thing a while ago.** I could add subtitles, and let the whole thing go down in one batch. Of course I had to add each file into the queue by hand. But that minor annoyance wasn't such a big deal. **But this only worked with one set of files.**

**I'm searching for a free or non-free tool that could do the job.**
I know I could just do a Google search... but there are so many applications available, I can't even decide which one to try.

Update:
The files are stored in a folder. Just one, no sub-folders. They are in .mkv format, and the subtitle(s) are inside the .mkv container. Sound(s) and video is the same, everything is in the same container.

Answer (score 1):

Freemake Video Converter is what you are looking for.

http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/

**EDIT:** It supports loading the subtitles from external source if subtitles aren't already present in the mkv container.

Also, it has one of the best user interface you will find in free video converters.

Comment: Instead of just posting a link to some software, please explain how exactly it solves the problem the OP is facing.

Comment: @slhck I don't know how to explain in this case. OP asked if there was a program which could batch convert video files with subtitles burned in, and I linked her to it. I will add some more details in the post though (based on your comment on the OP's post)

Comment: Looks awesome! I'll run a test-run with this software and see if it works.

Comment: Freemake has at least 4 (FOUR) virus warnings:    https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/04ad0f45dc4614cf6e538ec00ff7ef56b708cc4f4663f6fd8216a12ad5bafa04/detection

Comment: Correction: 4 out of 30-ish AV software detect it as a Potentially Unanted file

Answer (score 1):

I tried some portable converters for your specific case.

- [X-WinFF](http://www.winpenpack.com/en/download.php?view.1093) (a ffmpg GUI)
- [XMedia Recode](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.xmedia-recode.de/download.html)
- [Video to Video converter](http://www.videotovideo.org/download/)
- [MkvToMp4](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MkvToMp4)

Only one of them was able to handle embedded subtitles.

#### MkvToMp4

> MkvToMp4 can change the mkv container to Mp4 without transcoding video (If the original video in h264 format). Support for multiple internal and external audio tracks. Support subtitle formats: srt, ass, ssa, ttxt. Changing colors for subtitles. Add and edit tags for Mp4 files (m4v, m4a, m4b). Artworks and chapters for Mp4 files.

- head into the options and check *Load all internal subtitles* and mp4 as output format
- As you can see, it extracts embedded subtitles and adds them later to your .mp4

  [image]